# How does an SDK/framework works when included into xCode projects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, sdk

I am able to see the headers of the SDK, that means I am able to see what methods the SDK has but where is the actual implementation of those methods and how can I override the code that is automatically getting executed?

And what about the .a files of the SDK, is there a way to extract the content?

If you have links/documentation about all this can you please share it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks and libraries are written in such a way that owner does not want you to see how is it implemented or update the code. You can look in to this code http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios where in which how to create framework is mentioned. While creating the framework or library you would be doing all the implementation part. But while creating the framework the user will be seeing only the .h files

Comment: Very nice. I will have a look of it. Thanks!